# Alarmmanager setInexactRepeating time of trigger

Tags: alarmmanager

In Alarmmanager setInexactRepeating state, Android synchronises repeating alarms from multiple apps and fires them at the same time. So if I want my alarmmanager to trigger after every 1 hour, then what is the probability it will get triggered in the exact time. If it gets triggered along with other alarmmanagers, then what is the precise time of trigger?